# Please help my ListView stop vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, vertical-scrolling

I've created a `ListView` in a nested `LinearLayouts` with Horizontal scrolling in an attempt to display long records with the capability for Horizontal scrolling, but now I'm unable to scroll the `ListView` vertically.

Here is my XML setup.  Can you help me figure out why the `ListView` stop scrolling.  I've found several article tried difference Width, Height and Weight layout, but nothing seems to work.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ProductReview" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/lyellow_strip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/shell_strip" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVCancel"
    android:layout_width="27sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="224dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/btnCancel"
    android:onClick="Cancel"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel32" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="527dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:orientation = "horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code"
                android:layout_width="110sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Type"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
                android:layout_width="70sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/code"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Manu"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/manufacturer"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/visc40"
                android:layout_width="80sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Visc 40"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/visc100"
                android:layout_width="80sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visc40"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Visc 100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viscindex"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visc100"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Visc Index"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/den15c"
                android:layout_width="80sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viscindex"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Den@15c"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/den15c"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/visctext"
                android:layout_width="150sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Visc Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/baseoiltype"
                android:layout_width="150sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/visctext"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Base Oil Type"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name2"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/baseoiltype"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/baseoil"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name2"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Base Oil"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/additives"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/baseoil"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Additives"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name3"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/additives"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otheradditives"
                android:layout_width="200sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name3"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Other Properties"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/thickener"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/otheradditives"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Thickener"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nlgi"
                android:layout_width="70sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thickener"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="NLGI"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name4"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nlgi"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Product Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="20sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comments"
                android:layout_width="200sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/packages"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comments"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Packages"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/area"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/packages"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Areas"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/usage"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/area"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Usage"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="17sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4060dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation = "horizontal">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true" >

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

   </HorizontalScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is generally a bad practice. Even if you manage a way to accomplish it. It will make your UI very expensive in terms of memory. I suggest taking a moment and thinking about how you can create a bet user experience that accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: Don't use ListView inside ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what to do.  This is probably not the best way, but it work for us.  I put the column headers one linear layout and the ListView in another.  Thanks.